# How to write a function that handle exceptions from futures in Scala?

Tags: scala

Several times in my application, I handle the errors of a future the same way.

For instance I do:

```
future map(r => println(r)) recover { 
  case arithmeticException => log("arithmetic exception")
  case NonFatal(e) => log(e)
}
```

How can I extract a method from the recover part in order to reuse it elsewhere?

For instance, I would like to do something like:

```
def handleException(): PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = {
  case arithmeticException => log("arithmetic exception")
  case NonFatal(e) => log(e)
}
```

and use it like this:

```
future map(r => println(r)) recover { handleException() }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What's the problem? The example you give works well.

Comment: You can also just write `recover handleException` instead of `recover { handleException() }`, no need to wrap the partial function like that.

Comment: @Naetmul you are right... My example did not compile because of a wrong return type in handleException()...

Comment: @Jesper yep indeed it is nicer without the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val handleException: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = {
  case arithmeticException => log("arithmetic exception")
  case NonFatal(e) => log(e)
}

future.map(println).recover(handleException)
```